# Bring cursor to a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

I want to bring the cursor to a textbox when i clicked a button. How can i do that? I tried Focus() method but it didn't not work. The code is shown below.

```
CsNIPAddrTextBox.Focus();
CsNIPAddrTextBox.TabIndex = 1;
```

Comment: Where in your code are those two lines located?

Comment: Is there any other element that could be taking the focus after you assign it to the text box? More code is needed really.

Comment: No, i don't focus anything else. It's under click event of a treeview control.

Comment: No need to change the tabIndex.

Comment: @Aphelion true but that shouldnt have any effect on this issue.

Comment: If all else fails remove the control and add a new one and see if the issue still exists. .Focus() should work given that the control is capable of receiving focus and nothing else is taking the focus straight after.

Comment: @CSharpened That is why I added the comment ;) Perhaps he was thinking it was part of a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that's a 'proper' TextBox (i.e. not custom) then simply calling `Focus()` should work.  It might not, however, if it's read-only (I'm not sure - I've not tried.  I know you can get a caret in a read-only box, which implies it can get focus).  Certainly if it's not `Enabled` then you won't be able to set focus.

Check the `CanFocus` property is true - if it's not, then there might be some other reason preventing the control from receiving focus.

If that's `true`, however, and the caret still doesn't make it to the control - you need to verify that it is receiving it.  Add an event handler for the text box's [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus) event and breakpoint it to clarify that it gets hit.  My guess is that it your breakpoint will be hit.  If so - then the answer is that another process is setting focus to another control immediately after your button click occurs.  *For example, if you do this kind of thing in a validation event handler you'll get a similar result, because the Windows Forms pipeline is already in the process of changing controls when the handler is fired.*

Also - why are you setting `TabIndex=1`?  Generally `TabIndex` is set at design time and left alone (unless of course these are dynamically created).  Unless you have a *particular* reason for doing this I'd get rid of that line.  It doesn't have a bearing on why this would/wouldn't work - just an observation.

Comment: CanFocus property is true, i checked it. Focus() does not work, cursor does not go to textbox when i clicked.

Comment: Have you tried removing the control and double checking you add the correct control. A fresh text box control that has not been messed with should be capable of taking focus using .Focus(). If it still doesnt work then suggestion above for testing the GotFocus event is your next step.

Comment: @blabla so why did you accept this answer then if you found it didn't work?  Try Michay's answer and see if it works and if it does then you should accept it

Answer (score 21):

Try `textbox1.select()`. It's the best approach to bring your cursor to your textbox. It also selects content of the texbox which makes it easier for the user to edit what's inside the textbox.

Answer (score 5):

Edit again:

If you try to select a `TextBox` in the `Click` event of a `TreeView`, it usually fails, because after the `Click` event the `TreeNode` will be selected, making your previous `Focus()` or `Select()` useless. The workable way is, perhaps, calling them in a `Timer`.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 10;
t.Tick += new EventHandler((s,ev)=>textBox2.Focus());
t.Start();
```

This is more like a hack though...

Comment: No, i want to move tab to the textbox. This only moves mouse pointer to textbox1 location.

Comment: @petre have you checked my newest answer?

Answer (score 5):

Set theActiveControl property of the form

```
ActiveControl = yourtextbox
```

Comment: I had a similar problem where focus was not shifted to a textbox on a tabpage. Setting that control as form's active control worked ... without calling Focus() and SelectAll()

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [TextBox.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select.aspx)

For example

```
textbox1.Select(textbox1.Text.Length,0);
```

Sets the cursor to the end of the text in yout textbox.

Answer (score 2):

If i read right you are talking about moving mouse cursor to the textbox? - Then you can use code like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = 
     PointToScreen( 
            new Point( textBox1.Location.X + 5, textBox1.Location.Y + 5) 
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

I know many of you had provided answers, but this may be useful to some who weren't able to get from previous responses. 
This worked for me, setting `Select()` on input text had set the cursor to the textbox.

Have this in form constructor:

```
this.Activated += OnActivated;
```

Handler Code:

```
private void OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            txtUser.Select();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if `textbox.Multiline=true` and/or `textbox.WordWrap = true`, the cursor might be hiding at the bottom of the field.